# Finding out who modified site settings under SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-settings

Someone today at my office went into a site collection under SharePoint, site settings, site navigation and change the navigation menu links.  Is there a way to find out the name (or username) of the person who did this modification from SharePoint 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it'll be in the ULS, look for POST entries around "/_layouts/quiklnch.aspx" or just ask the Site Collection Administrators who did it :)